# firefox extension working on page load

Tags: firefox-addon

I'm trying to create my first extension.

I've found this sample: http://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2009/01/28/how-to-develop-a-firefox-extension/

I need to get some html content on a specific page and write something in the same page, so I modified it and got what I needed (with javascript I added content in the table I want). But to view my content I have to launch the extension from the button on the status bar, while I would like to have it already active in the page as I load/reload it (with a check on the url so to have it working only on that page) but I can't have it automatically.

I tried to add linkTargetFinder.run(); on init area, but... nothing. Moreover the extension as an "autorun" but eve if active, I don0t see any change.

any working sample?

Thanks
Nadia

Here it is the code (I edited just the .js file), I commented a couple of test not working...

```
var linkTargetFinder = function () {
var prefManager = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/preferences-service;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIPrefBranch);
return {
    init : function () {
        gBrowser.addEventListener("load", function () {
            var autoRun = prefManager.getBoolPref("extensions.linktargetfinder.autorun");
            if (autoRun) {
                linkTargetFinder.run();
            }
            //linkTargetFinder.run();  // doesn't work
        }, false);
        //linkTargetFinder.run();  // doesn't work
        alert("ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ"); // doesn't work
    },

    run : function () {
        var head = content.document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0],
            style = content.document.getElementById("link-target-finder-style"),
            allLinks = content.document.getElementsByTagName("a"),
            foundLinks = 0;

        if (!style) {
            style = content.document.createElement("link");
            style.id = "link-target-finder-style";
            style.type = "text/css";
            style.rel = "stylesheet";
            style.href = "chrome://linktargetfinder/skin/skin.css";
            head.appendChild(style);
        }   

        for (var i=0, il=allLinks.length; i<il; i++) {
            elm = allLinks[i];
            if (elm.getAttribute("target")) {
                elm.className += ((elm.className.length > 0)? " " : "") + "link-target-finder-selected";
                foundLinks++;
            }
        }
        if (foundLinks === 0) {
            alert("No links found with a target attribute");
        }
        else {
            //alert("Found " + foundLinks + " links with a target attribute");
        }
        t = content.document.getElementById("ERSContainer"), // ID of the table
        d = t.getElementsByTagName("tr")[1],
        r = d.getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
        var myMail = "mail: "+r.textContent; //ok scrive nella td
        var myName =  content.document.getElementById("buyercontactname").value;
        var myAddr1 =  content.document.getElementById("buyeraddress1").value;
        var myAddr2 =  content.document.getElementById("buyeraddress2").value;
        var myCity =  content.document.getElementById("buyercity").value;
        var myProv =  content.document.getElementById("buyerstateprovince").value;
        var myCAP =  content.document.getElementById("buyerzip").value;

        var elt = content.document.getElementById("buyercountry");
        var myCountry =  elt.options[elt.selectedIndex].text;
        var myTel =  content.document.getElementById("dayphone1").value;
        var myTag1 = "<tr><td colspan='2'>OK!!!<br />";
        var myTag2 = "</td></tr>";


        z= t.innerHTML;

        t.innerHTML  = myTag1 + myMail +
         " - "+myName+
        myAddr1 + "<br />" +
        myAddr2 + "<br />" +
        myCity + "<br />" +
        myProv + "<br />" +
        myCAP + "<br />" +
        myCountry + "<br />" +
        myTel + "<br />" +
        myFlash+
         myTag2+z;

    }
};
}();
window.addEventListener("load", linkTargetFinder.init, false);
```

Comment: Could you show us your code?

Comment: code added... It seems that the code called in the init function doesn't run on page load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you are doing is running a bit of JavaScript on a specific web page, like adding content into a table, maybe you should consider doing a userscript for the [Greasemonkey addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) instead of a full addon. With this you write your JS for the page and it gets executed each time you browse this specific page.

edit:

Try with this :

```
init: function () {
   gBrowser.addEventListener("load", linkTargetFinder.run, true);
},
...
```

Comment: Thanks Yolanda, but I have to give the add-on to complete a software written in adobe AIR. I want to give to the users an add-on ready to be installed. I can not tell them "download Greasemonkey and add this js code"

Answer (score 0):

I bet that the `extensions.linktargetfinder.autorun` does not exist. So `getBoolPref` throws an exception and the rest is history.

Change your code to the following

```js
var autoRun;
try {
  autoRun = prefManager.getBoolPref("extensions.linktargetfinder.autorun");
} catch(e){
  autoRun = false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I modified the sample I found on that link, It has the autorun option (even if I haven't seen any difference) So it is not missing. Anyway I tried to add the call even out of the "if (autoRun)" and it didn't work anyway.

I solved with Yolanda script. Thanks anyway!